# Show different content based on language using Ampscript code

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I want to show in one content area different content based on language. If EN and SV show 6 logos, all the other languages show 2 logos.

Bare in mind that on the top of the mailer I already make a statement to make EN as default if some other language is chosen beside the ones we offer.

I tried to use the code below. But it tells me that Language is is an invalid comparison "*The script condition contains an invalid comparison operator.
Condition: @Language = EN*"

```
<!--%%[
SET @RS = LOOKUPROWS("ALLCOM_SHARED_SOCIALLOGOS","Region",@Region,"Language",@Language)

]%%-->

<!--%%[ /* if language = EN and SV */

if @Language = EN AND @Language = SV then

 SET @SOCIALLOGOS_URL1 = FIELD(ROW(@RS,1),"URL1") 
 SET @SOCIALLOGOS_URL2 = FIELD(ROW(@RS,1),"URL2") 
 SET @SOCIALLOGOS_URL3 = FIELD(ROW(@RS,1),"URL3") 
 SET @SOCIALLOGOS_URL4 = FIELD(ROW(@RS,1),"URL4") 
 SET @SOCIALLOGOS_URL5 = FIELD(ROW(@RS,1),"URL5") 
 SET @SOCIALLOGOS_URL6 = FIELD(ROW(@RS,1),"URL6") 

]%%-->

<a href="%%=v(@SOCIALLOGOS_URL1)=%%">
           <img src="http://www.thebetwaygroup.com/m/betway/sports/0413/main/dark/appstore.png" width="88" height="29" border="0" style="margin-right: 20px;" />
</a>
<a href="%%=v(@SOCIALLOGOS_URL2)=%%">
         <img src="http://www.thebetwaygroup.com/m/betway/sports/0413/main/dark/android.png" width="91" height="29" border="0" style="margin-right: 20px;" />
</a>
<a href="%%=v(@SOCIALLOGOS_URL3)=%%" target="_blank">
       <img src="http://www.thebetwaygroup.com/m/betway/sports/0413/main/dark/facebook.png" width="30" height="30" border="0" style="margin-right: 20px;">
 </a>
 <a href="%%=v(@SOCIALLOGOS_URL4)=%%" target="_blank">
       <img src="http://www.thebetwaygroup.com/m/betway/sports/0413/main/dark/twitter.png" width="37" height="30" border="0" style="margin-right: 20px;">
 </a>
 <a href="%%=v(@SOCIALLOGOS_URL5)=%%" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://www.thebetwaygroup.com/m/betway/sports/0413/main/dark/youtube.png" width="43" height="29" border="0" style="margin-right: 20px;">
  </a>
  <a href="%%=v(@SOCIALLOGOS_URL6)=%%" target="_blank">
       <img src="http://www.thebetwaygroup.com/m/betway/sports/0413/main/dark/gplus.png" width="30" height="30" border="0" style="margin-right: 20px;" />
   </a>
<!--%%[ else /* all other languages */

 SET @SOCIALLOGOS_URL1 = FIELD(ROW(@RS,1),"URL1") 
   SET @SOCIALLOGOS_URL2 = FIELD(ROW(@RS,1),"URL2")

]%%-->

<a href="%%=v(@SOCIALLOGOS_URL1)=%%">
           <img src="http://www.thebetwaygroup.com/m/betway/sports/0413/main/dark/appstore.png" width="88" height="29" border="0" style="margin-right: 20px;" />
 </a>
  <a href="%%=v(@SOCIALLOGOS_URL2)=%%">
          <img src="http://www.thebetwaygroup.com/m/betway/sports/0413/main/dark/android.png" width="91" height="29" border="0" style="margin-right: 20px;" />
  </a>


<!--%%[ endif ]%%-->
```

thanks

Fran

Comment: I answered below,  however not sure where the `@Region` and `@Language` are being set.  I'm assuming that is already done in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You AMPscript is using a single = for the comparison.  It should be

```
if @Language == "EN" OR @Language == "SV" then
```

Also notice the quotes.  I assume you are comparing a string,  so it requires the quotes. I also used the "or" statement to capture one or the other as matching,  instead of both,  which is what the "and"  statement does.

Let me know if that fixed it.